# Word or Phrase for Identical Twins with Opposite Personalities?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Looking for an apt word or phrase for physically identical twins with opposing character traits? Example: one twin tends to be very organized, and the other tends to be very disorganized, etc.

Comment: Polar opposites?

Comment: Yin and yang perhaps?

Comment: An information theorist might describe them as having Hamming distance one.

Comment: If they fight, it would be a Shadow Match.

Answer (score 6):

> **mirror image** (*noun*): something that looks like something else but with its left and right sides reversed. [Merriam-Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mirror%20image)

Comment: Yes. Probably the best choice. Additionally one could think about describing them in a narrative context as 2 points at the opposing ends of a line; they developed their character traits in different directions but started at the same point. Or two points at the same height(Yvalue) of a parable starting in 0. though these would just be other ways of describing the same principle.

Answer (score 0):

If your twins are identical in every way, except in organization, I can only come up with **"almost identical"** and  I don't think there is a single word for that. Of course you can also say "very much alike" but that's not a single word either, and if you just say "they are alike", it doesn't mean they are identical in every aspect except one.